# Cartoon science fiction TV show where a group of four friends meet friendly aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

- The main character has orange hair or something and also has dots in his face
- The female character wears a beret
- The male protagonist meets a alien who become friend and tells his friends in school and one day discover a hidden lab under a shed
- The main character also does not know anything about his father

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!